# Issue with multiple loops to create plots, getting error

Tags: python, loops, matplotlib, pandas

Basically I have been trying to create plots from dataframes. First I define the dataframes (glist) then the y values (alist) to plot against the dates. They all work individually but not in this loop. Any suggestions?

EDITS: Issue now is that the first plot is being repinted for all the other plots when I call them. I have tried to use plt.clr() at the beginning of the loop but doesnt appear to work.

```
x,y,= (0.5,-.16)
fmt = DateFormatter('%m/%d/%Y')
nlist=[]
def plots():

Totrigs,TotOrDV,TotOrH,TotGas,TotOil,TotBit,ABFl,ABOr,SKFl,SKOr,BCOr,MBFl,MBOr = dataforgraphs()
glist = [Totrigs,ABFl,ABOr,SKFl,SKOr,BCOr,MBFl,MBOr]
alist = [['Total Rigs'],['GAS','OIL','BIT'],[['HZ','DIR/VERT']],[['GAS','OIL']],[['HZ','DIR/VERT']],['OIL'],[['HZ','DIR/VERT']],[['HZ','DIR/VERT']]]

for i,k in zip(glist,alist):
    fig = i.plot(y=k,linewidth=2.0, legend=False)
    fig.patch.set_facecolor('#EEECE1')
    fig.xaxis.set_major_formatter(fmt)
    fig.legend(loc= 'upper center',bbox_to_anchor=(x,y),fancybox=True)
    nlist.append(fig)

    return (nlist)

def Totgraph():
nlist = plots()
Totrigs = nlist[0]           
plt.savefig('C:\\Python33\\XcelFiles\\Pics\\Totrigs.png',bbox_inches='tight')
plt.clf()

def ABFLgraph():
nlist = plots()
ABFl = nlist[1]
plt.title('Alberta Fluid Type')
plt.savefig('C:\\Python33\\XcelFiles\\Pics\\ABFl.png',bbox_inches='tight')
```

Comment: What line are you getting the error on ?

Comment: I am thinking `fig = i.plot(y=alist[x],sharex=True, linewidth=2.0, legend=False)` is your problem. In this case your `y = alist[x]` which is a list. I am thinking that y cannot be a list and that is why it is giving you this error.

Comment: what should I turn alist into in order for it to read it as the column labels for the y values?

Comment: @Elias the `plot` method on a `DataFrame` takes a list of arguments (also `sharex` defaults to `True`).  Without more information, it is difficult to answer.  What line is the error on?  What is `y` and `fmt`?  Do all your `DataFrames` have the same columns and types?  Why are you indexing using `x` instead of using `k` directly?

Comment: There I make the adjustments and returned to an error I was getting previously.

Comment: here i will edit the post so you can see the definitions above.

Comment: ... the code in your error does not appear in your post.  However, you now have `alist[k]`. `k` is an element of `alist`.  Try using `y=k` instead.  (and delete `x=0` and `x+=1` if you're using them to position your legend)

Comment: Tried y=k and got rid of the x counter. still results in same error.

Comment: Which error?  the `ValueError`?  Because that is not valid syntax, but also is not what you have in your code...

Comment: yes the value error, what is the valid syntax for that? Sorry I am relearning python from a course 4 years ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sample data:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':[1,2,3,4], 'y':[10,20,30,40], 'z':[100,200,300,400]})

d_list = [df, df, df, df]
y_list = [['z'], ['y'], ['y', 'z']]
```

Your code should be something like this:

```
x,y,= (0.5,-.16)
fmt = DateFormatter('%m/%d/%Y')
res = []
for g in glist:
    for a in alist:
        fig = g.plot(x='x', y=a, sharex=True, linewidth=2.0, legend=False))
        fig.patch.set_facecolor('#EEECE1')
        # my x axis isn't dates, but you get the picture...
        # fig.xaxis.set_major_formatter(fmt)
        fig.legend(loc= 'upper center',bbox_to_anchor=(x,y),fancybox=True)
        res.append(fig)
```

The code you're erroring on currently:

```
for g, a in glist, alist:
    print g, a
```

Is not valid python.  You need to have nested loops like you have in your code in the question.  Or you can use things like `zip` to get pairs:

```
for g, a in zip(glist, alist):
    print g, a
```

Comment: `The code you're erroring on currently: for d, y in d_list, y_list: print d, y` I don't see that in his code?

Comment: The zip worked!! thanks man. Basically the issue was that both needed to be read through the loop at the same time because i created the plot, and simultaneously k have it which columns to use.

Comment: Yea it would be nice if he showed the actual line that is errored. Nice job

Comment: @Justin having a reprinting error. I think i know why it is happening but not sure how to fix it. My attempts have been futile. I edited the orginal post.

Comment: @carevans88 As amazing as I am, I am not intuitive enough to understand this.  Please revert your edit, accept my above answer and ask a new question that, if needed, links to this one.  Make sure you include all the pertinent information including the exact error.  However, in your edit, `plt` doesn't exist.  You need to reference the returned object, e.g. `Totrigs.savefig`.

Comment: @Justin Here I have created a new post."Error in multiloop of plots, first plot appears over other plots"